# Узнать координаты любого элемента двумерного массива

Tags: python

Всем привет. У меня возникла проблема, мне нужно узнать координаты любого элемента в двумерном массиве. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Я полагаю вам поможет numpy.where()

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [1, 5, 6]])
i, j = np.where(x == 1)
print(i, j)
```